# Bootstrap 3 Tabs displays content from 2 tab-pane's

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a tab running in a BS3 modal as show below.

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="ghTab">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#Step1" data-target=".Step1" data-toggle="tab">Step 1 of 5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Step2" data-target=".Step2" data-toggle="tab">Step 2 of 5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Step3" data-target=".Step3" data-toggle="tab">Step 3 of 5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Step4" data-target=".Step4" data-toggle="tab">Step 4 of 5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Step5" data-target=".Step5" data-toggle="tab">Step 5 of 5</a></li>
 </ul>
```

With the tab content...

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active Step1">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active Step2">
    </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade in active Step3">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active Step4">
    </div>
     <div class="tab-pane fade in active Step5">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have noticed that randomly when i click on a tab it show 2 tab panes content. If i then click on another tab and back again the problem get corrected.

Could this be a bug in the version of BS I am using (Bootstrap v3.0.2)?

S

Comment: Why do you have all of them active?

Answer (score 3):

You have all of your tab-content div items as **in** and **active**, which tells bootstrap to show them onload... You need to restructure your tab classes as seen below:

```
<div class="tab-content">
<!-- Only the first one should be active as it will show on page load automaticall -->
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active Step1">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade Step2">
    </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade Step3">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade Step4">
    </div>
     <div class="tab-pane fade Step5">
    </div>
</div>
```